# Connectors for a RS485 multipoint bus

Tags: connector, rs485, modbus

I need to connect a bunch of Mass Flow Controllers on a RS485 (TIA-485-A) multipoint bus. I will use Modbus protocol to communicate with the devices.

As specified on modbus.org ([Specification and Implementation guidelines](http://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_over_serial_line_V1_02.pdf)), the serial bus infrastructure in a multipoint Serial Line system is like this:

[image: Modbus connectors]

In my project, I would need only the Passive TAP (no Active TAP), because the length of my cables are around 10 cm.

From the mechanical point of view, 2 types of connectors are specified. The RJ45, and the D-shell 9-pin, as depicted below.

[image: Modbus - serial bus infrastructure]

My question is, **what can I found on the market as Passive TAP with either RJ45 or D-Shell 9-pin connectors?**

Something like this with RJ45/D-Shell instead M12 would be nice. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likewise, L-Com (http://www.l-com.com) makes a DB9 Y splitter, available on the web.

Comment: Excellent! It´s exactly what I was dreaming of.

Answer (score 0):

There are RJ45 Y-splitters on the market, to be used for ISDN. These are completely passive and wired one-to-one.